# Solving a non-zero quadratic equation of two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics, quadratic-forms

I have a problem where I am to find the intersection between the two curves
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2 - y^2 = 3 \\
xy = 2,
\end{cases}
$$
which I can easily see that the two points $\pm(2,1)$ are the real solutions to this problem, but I don't know how to solve for this systematically. I tried two approaches to solve for it as a quadratic equation:

**approach 1** (insert the second equation in the first):

$$
4x^2 - 4y^2 + 4xy = 20 \Leftrightarrow (2x + y)^2 - 5y^2 = 20 \Leftrightarrow x=\dfrac{\pm\sqrt{5y^2 + 20} - y}{2}
$$

**approach 2** (substitute $y$ for $x$):

$$
x=\frac{2}{y} \Rightarrow x^2 - \frac{4}{x^2} = 3 \Leftrightarrow x^4 - 3x^2 - 4 = 0
$$

But I don't know how to continue from here. I found [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111486/solving-the-equation-y2-x2-xy-0#111491/) where they solve a similar equation using these two approaches, but they don't end up with a constant under the root since they have $0$ on the right-hand side. Also, since that equation don't have any real solutions, I don't get how to apply it to this equation.

How do I solve this kind of equation systematically? (not 100% sure what type of the equation it is)

### Edits:

Corrected substitution from incorrectly substituting $y$ for $y$. I had arrived at this step earlier, but I still don't know how to solve the equation.

Comment: How exactly did you get $x^2-\frac{4}{y^2}=3$?

Comment: Oh... I incorrectly substituted $y$ for $x$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiply the first equation by $x^2$ and substitute $xy$ from the second:

$$x^4-x^2y^2-3x^2=x^4-4-3x^2=0.$$

This is a biquadratic equation, which gives the roots $x^2=4$ and $x^2=-1$. If you are only interested in the real solutions,

$$x=\pm2,y=\frac2x.$$

Comment: Yup, this is the step I didn't do correctly!

Answer (score 8):

$$\begin{cases}
x^2 - y^2 = 3 \\
xy = 2,
\end{cases}$$

Substitution is as follows, you substitute $y$ in first equation with it's value according to second equation so in this case. 
$$x^2-\frac4{x^2}=3$$
That is $y=2/x$ according to second equation. Substitution should always lead to reduction in number of variables.

Solving $x^2-\frac4{x^2}=3$ for $x$ yields $$x^4 -3x^2-4=0.$$ This equation has two real solutions $x=2$ and $x=-2$ (there are also two complex solutions at $x=i$ and $x=-i$). Plugging $x= \pm 2$ into the initial equations yields $y=\pm 1$. Likewise, you can obtain the complex solutions of $y$ by plugging $x=\pm i$ into the initial equations which yields $y=\pm 2i$.

Comment: This still doesn't show how the values are solved for. It's just as easy to see in the original equations. *"substitution should always lead to reduction in number of variables"* is a good point 'though!

Comment: Values are solved for using methods used to solve quadratic equations. Here it is assumed that you know how to solve quadratics.

Comment: I am confident at solving many quadratics, but I believe that *approach 1* in my question shows that I don't know how to solve that kind of quadratic equation systematically.

Comment: @BCI4evry1: I'm not sure what you were trying to do in approach 1 but approach 2 gives you a quadratic in $x^2$. Or alternatively you can substitute $z=x^2$ to get a more traditional looking quadratic that you can solve.

Comment: I'm not sure anymore what I was referring to in my last comment. What you say about approach 2 is correct, and is the step I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 4):

An idea for you:

Multiply second equation by two: $\;2xy=4\;$ , and subtract it from first equation, getting:

$$x^2-2xy-(y^2-1)=0$$

The solution to this quadratic in $\;x\;$ is:

$$\Delta=4y^2+4y^2-4=4(2y^2-1)\implies x_{1,2}=y\pm\sqrt{2y^2-1}$$

and now substitute in first equation, say:

$$\overbrace{y^2\pm2y\sqrt{2y^2-1}+2y^2-1}^{=x^2}-y^2=3\implies y^2\pm y\sqrt{2y^2-1}=2\implies$$

$$y^4-4y^2+4=2y^4-y^2\implies y^4+3y^2-4=0\iff (y^2+4)(y^2-1)=0\implies$$

$$y=\pm1\implies x=\pm1\pm\sqrt{2-1}=\pm1\pm1$$

and since the solutions $\;(x,y)\;$ must have the same sign and both are clearly different from zero, we finally get the candidates:

$$(2,1)\,,\,\,(-2,-1)$$

Finally, check whether the above two really are solutions (since we squared stuff here...)

Comment: This is a little more tedious isn't it. Are there situations when this might be preferred over substitution.

Comment: Well, more tedious than *what*? The OP wrote he substituted at once and messed up and etc. I just tried to offer her/him an option to work out things a little differently at the beginning...

Comment: I meant in this particular situation the method you have shown looks more tedious than substitution. I was asking if there are some cases that you know of when this might be easier to do than substitution.

Comment: This is substitution, its just that rather than substitute $x=y/2$ we are calculating a much more complicated way of expressing x in terms of y and susbtituting that instead. I have to say though I think if the OP had trouble substituting $x=y/2$ then thinking they are going to do the above without any mistakes seems... optimistic?

Comment: @Chris I don't know if that's optimistic or not: that's up to the OP. The OP showed a way when substituting is the first step, and I showed a different way when substituting arrives later and, imo, an easier way. The OP has now two ways to approach this problem: let us let her/him decide which one fits him'her better.

Comment: I guess easier is subjective... :)

Answer (score 4):

Your second approach would have been my choice as well. Once you've found that
$$x^4-3x^2-4=0,$$
you can solve this as a quadratic in $x$ to find that $x^2=-1$ or $x^2=4$, as others have explained.

Your first approach is also fine, though your choice of substitution is not. You can see that
$$y^2=x^2-3,$$
and squaring the second equation yields
$$4=x^2y^2=x^2(x^2-3)=x^4-3x^2,$$
leading to the same equation for $x$ as your first approach.

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake during calculation. What you should have done during substitution is to get the value $x=\frac2y$ from the second equation and substitute $x$ with that value in the first equation which should result in

$$\left(\frac{2}{y}\right)^2 - y^2=3$$ which is an equation that is easy to solve.

Comment: I don't think it is easy to solve systematically. It is easy to see the solutions, but I'm asking for the systematic approach to this.

Comment: @BCI4evry1 It's easy to solve if you introduce the correct substitution.

Comment: Care to show how?

Comment: @BCI4evry1 I think just telling you that you should introduce a new variable should be enough. It's time for you to put some effort into solving the equation. The substitution (and some algebraic manipulation) should lead you to a quadrativ equation.

Comment: Damnit, you are right. I had already tried substituting $u = x^2$ but I first arrived at the rubbish $u = \pm\sqrt{-7/4} + 3/2$... of course I had made a mistake with a sign, so it should have been $u = \pm\sqrt{25/4} + 3/2$, giving me $u = \frac{3\pm 5}{2} = \{-1, 4\}$. meaning that $x=\pm 2$ if u is real.

Comment: @BCI4evry1 Glad to hear you made it.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, based on (complex) completing of the square.
Notice that if the first equation would have the term $x^2+y^2$, it would be much easier because then by taking the sum and the difference of the two equation, you would get squares. But the minus sign in front of the $y$ is ''wrong'', so let's change it using complex numbers!
$$(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy=3+4i$$
$$(x-iy)^2=x^2-y^2-2ixy=3-4i$$
Write the numbers in the polar form,
$$(x+iy)^2=5 e^{i\phi}$$
$$(x-iy)^2=5 e^{-i\phi}$$
Here $\phi$ is such that $\tan(\phi)=4/3$.
So, take the square roots:
$$x+iy=\sqrt{5} e^{i\phi/2}$$
$$x-iy=\sqrt{5} e^{-i\phi/2}$$
Take the sum and the difference:
$$x=\sqrt{5} \frac{e^{i\phi/2}+e^{-i\phi/2}}{2}$$
$$y=\sqrt{5} \frac{e^{i\phi/2}-e^{-i\phi/2}}{2i}$$
Remember the complex equations for sine and cosine:
$$x=\sqrt{5} \cos(\phi/2)$$
$$y=\sqrt{5} \sin(\phi/2)$$

To find $\cos(\phi/2)$ (thanks to hints from Michael Seifert in the comments): It is easy to see that $\cos(\phi)=3/5$. The double-angle formula for cosine says:
$$\cos(\phi)=2 \cos^2(\phi/2)-1$$
so
$$\cos(\phi/2)=\pm \sqrt{\frac{\cos(\phi)+1}{2}}=\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$
And likewise $\sin(\phi/2)=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Altogether, this leads to the solution given by others! This might not be the easiest method to discover, especially not the last step, but I always like it if complex numbers are used to solve a problem in the reals.

Comment: If $\tan \phi = 4/3$, then $\phi$ forms one angle of a 3-4-5 triangle.  This implies that $\sin \phi = 4/5$ and $\cos \phi = 3/5$.  You can then use the equations $\cos \phi = 2 \cos^2 (\phi/2) - 1 = 1 - \sin^2(\phi/2)$ to find $\cos (\phi/2)$ and $\sin (\phi/2)$.

Comment: *Suddenly, a new world of possibilities for completing the square opens up*. I've never seen this before. Neat answer!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: thanks, added to the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Once you get to $x^4-3x^2-4=0$, it follows quite easily. You can factor this as $(x^2-4)(x^2+1)$, or if you want to do it more systematically, you can do a substitution $u= x^2$. Then you have $u^2-3u-4=0$ and now you can apply the quadratic formula to solve for $u$.

Comment: That should be $(x^2 - 4)(x^2 + 1)$. But it is also the answer Servaes gave hours ago.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The OP asked for "systematic" solution. The quadratic formula is more systematic than factoring.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to find real solutions, here is an approach using trigonometry:

The equation is equivalent to $z^{2} = 3+4i$ where $z=x+yi$. Hence, there exists two solutions $z=\pm (3+4i)^{1/2}$. Using a polar coordinate, if $z=re^{i\theta}$, we should have
$$
r= \sqrt{|3+4i|} = \sqrt{5}, \quad \cos 2\theta = \frac{3}{5},\quad  \sin 2\theta = \frac{4}{5}
$$
From this, we have 
$$
\tan 2\theta = \frac{4}{3} = \frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^{2}\theta}, \quad \tan\theta = \frac{1}{2}
$$
and
$$
z = \pm \sqrt{5}(\cos\theta + i\sin \theta) = \pm (2+i),
$$
which gives two solutions $\pm(2, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

With *symmetric functions*:

First it's enough to determine $x^2$ and $y^2$ since

$$\begin{cases}
x^2-y^2=3\\ xy=2
\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}
x^2-y^2=3\\x^2y^2=4&\text{and $x$, $y$ have the same sign.}
\end{cases}$$
So we  set $X=x^2$,$\;Y=y^2$. We have to solve the system
$\;\begin{cases}
X-Y=3,\\ XY=4,\end{cases}$ in positive numbers.

This system implies 
$\; (X+Y)^2=(X-Y)^2+4XY=9+16=25 $ , so we obtain the system
$$\begin{cases}
X+Y=5,\\ XY=4,\end{cases}\iff \begin{gathered}\{X,Y\}\;\text{ are the (positive) solutions of the quadratic equation }\\[1ex] T^2-5T+4=0
\end{gathered}$$
Now  the solutions of this equation are $\{1,4\}$, and we have $X=Y+3>Y$, so the solution are $x^2=X=4,\;y^2=Y=1$, whence
$$(x,y)=(2,1)\;\text{or}\;(x,y)=(-2,-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

I thought about removing the constant terms.

$$2x^2-2y^2 = 6 = 3xy$$

$$ 2x^2 - 3xy -2y^2 = 0$$

$$(2x+y)(x-2y) = 0$$

$$\text{$y = -2x$ or $y=\frac 12x$}$$

Substituting into $xy=2$, I get

$$\text{$(x,y)\in \{(i,-2i), (-i,2i), (-2,-1),(2,1) \}$}$$